# Increment of column ID

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-connection

I've got two methods, one is used to insert data into db, the another one is to delete them. So let's say I've added 3 rows which have id=1, id=2, id=3. Now i decided to delete the last one and again insert 1 row. so insted of having three rows with ids 1,2,3 I've got three rows with ids 1,2,4. How can i fix this?

```
 private void insert() throws SQLException {

    String query = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, user_group_id) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);";

 PreparedStatement sql = Boot.getCon().prepareStatement(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS); 
    sql.setString(1, username);
    sql.setString(2, email);
    sql.setString(3, password);
    sql.setInt(4,user_group_id);
    sql.executeUpdate();

}

public static void delete(int id) throws SQLException {

    String query = "DELETE FROM users where id=?;";
    PreparedStatement statement = Boot.getCon().prepareStatement(query);
    statement.setInt(1,id);
    statement.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println("You have deleted 1 row");
}
```

Comment: Just an advice, don't try to fix it, just let the id work as it is don't care about the difference between ids

Answer (score 0):

this is not a problem in the first place, this is how the AUTO_INCREMENT WORKS...
if you want to fix it, then you gotta make some more coding, i can tell you about some ideas if you are not lazy and intrested.

remove the AUTO_INCREMENT FROM YOUR INDEX, make a column called ID, just make it INT type, then you gotta make a function like that:

```
private int returnLastID(){
//Make your Connection to the database things here.
String query="SELECT ID FROM table_name ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1";
//prepare your statement into the resultset variable then simply return it.
return resultSet.getInt("ID");
}
```

like that everytime you insert a new record, you just call this function and make +1 to it.
hope you like it.

Comment: i'd love to hear about it

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't look like an issue, this is the expected behaviour. Your code is fine.

I believe you are using some sequence in the background to assign ids. Every time you will insert, the sequence value will get incremented by 1.

If you delete any row, that id will not get used again.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete permanent in a database you  will make sure creating gaps in your identity seed.
Often solutions work with deleted flags, 1 = Deleted. If creating gaps is no go for you (compliance reasons) consider to update a deleted column rather than hard delete.

Altering identity seed is possible using the following queries:

SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); 
SET IDENTITY=4;

Identity seed is incremental, setting the identity seed lower than the maximum value will not work.